# Trying to add xmlns:xsi attribute to element

Tags: attributes, xslt-1.0, xml-namespaces, xsi

I'm using XSLT 1.0 to produce an XML document where the desired output looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03" **xmlns:xsi="
       http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"**>

...

    </Document>
```

I've tried several things including the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
    <xsl:template match="/VendorPayments">
      <xsl:element name="Document" namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03">
        <xsl:attribute name="xsi" namespace="xmlns">http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance</xsl:attribute>

    ...

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

... and this variation for the xsl:attribute tag:

```
<xsl:attribute name="xsi" namespace="xmlns">
    <xsl:text>http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance</xsl:text>
</xsl:attribute>
```

... and this one:

```
<xsl:attribute name="xsi" namespace="xmlns">
    <xsl:value-of select="'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'"/>
</xsl:attribute>
```

In every case, my result looks the same:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document xp_0:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03" xmlns:xp_0="xmlns">
    ...
</Document>
```

I also tried removing the xsl:attribute tag altogether and instead modifying the xsl:stylesheet tag like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

... but this produces the following result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03">
    ...
</Document>
```

... which is correct except for the missing xmlns:xsi attribute. I could really use some help here!

Comment: Couldn't be it a msxsl issue? Have you tried it with another processor? In Altova it's working for me exactly as you need.

Comment: Perhaps, I'm not sure. I'm just running this through some .NET code as follows:

<code>
System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
transform.Load(xslt);
transform.Transform(xmlInput, xmlOutput);
</code>